# how can I integrate jenkins with openam for authentication?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, oauth, saml, openam

My requirement is to integrate jenkins with openam, if i put the jenkins URL in the browser it should automatically redirect to openam after providing the credential it should redirect back to jenkins and open the jenkins dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use J2EE Aget if Jenkins is deployed on Tomcat, Jetty or JBoss or ...

Or you can use SAML Plugin for Jenkins. In this case, OpenAM acts as a SAML IdP. 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SAML+Plugin

This page may help you:
http://troubleshootingrange.blogspot.jp/2012/11/using-openam-for-jenkins-hudson.html

Comment: thanks for the reply...I followed the first method and was able to succeed but the problem is after integrating i'm not able to perform the webhook from bitbucket. It is not validating..

Comment: I'm not able to find out the metadata for jenkins to follow the second approach.

Comment: How about [Not Enforced URIs](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/admin-guide/chap-agents#j2ee-agent-not-enforced-uri-properties)?

Comment: I will look into it.